# Why description field is not adding when creating Jira Rest API app

Tags: jira-rest-api

unable to create description while creating Jira Rest API post method.

```
"**project": {
        "key": project_key
    },
    "summary": summary,
    "issuetype": {
        "name": issue_type
    },
    **"description":description,**

    "assignee": {
        "id": assignee
    },
    "labels": [label]  # Assuming label is a variable containing the label name
}
```

"project": {
"key": project_key
},
"summary": summary,
"issuetype": {
"name": issue_type
},
"description":description,

```
    "assignee": {
        "id": assignee
    },
    "labels": [label]  # Assuming label is a variable containing the label name
}**
```

This is my json code except description other things are working perfect.
[error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ehXl.png)